# How to call an event handler with parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
var MyParameter = ...;
var options = {
  ...,
  actions: [
    {
      label: 'TheLabel',
      eventHandler: MyEventHandler
    }
  ],
  ...
};
```

But then I have this:

```
function MyEventHandler(MyParameter) {...}
```

How do I pass the parameter in the callback function reference?

Comment: [Function#bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) perhaps - not sure, your question is unclear

Comment: @zer00ne I don't want to copy-paste all the code and the problem is quite clear.

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs It is unclear to me because I don't know whether you want to call the listener one time, programmatically (i.e., outside the context of an actual event) with a particular value, or if you want to ensure that the function is always supplied the given argument every time it is invoked, forever. In that case, it's not totally clear to me why you need an argument at all. (I can think of a few reasons why, but it don't know which apply for your case, if that is indeed your case.)

Comment: @apsillers I don't need to call the listener explicitly. All I need is my function to be supplied with the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bind() to make a function with pre-specified initial arguments.

```
options = {
    ..., 
    actions:[{
         label: 'TheLabel',
          eventHandler: MyEventHandler.bind(this, MyParameter);
   }],
    ...
};
```